# With google-cloud-bigquery, how can I create table and soon after that, insert rows?

Tags: python, google-bigquery

I'm using google-cloud-bigquery, `google-cloud-bigquery==3.11.4`, on Python. I want to write a code that if there is table already, it insert rows and if not, it creates table and insert rows.
I tried several codes but apparenlty, on the step of row insertion, the table is not detected.
These are the code I tried.

```py
from google.cloud.bigquery import Client, SchemaField, Table

from dcraft.domain.layer.base import Metadata
from dcraft.interface.metadata.base import MetadataRepository

METADATA_TABLE_SCHEMA = [
    SchemaField("id", "STRING", mode="REQUIRED"),
    SchemaField("project_name", "STRING", mode="REQUIRED"),
    SchemaField("layer", "STRING", mode="REQUIRED"),
    SchemaField("content_type", "STRING", mode="REQUIRED"),
    SchemaField("author", "STRING", mode="NULLABLE"),
    SchemaField("created_at", "DATETIME", mode="REQUIRED"),
    SchemaField("description", "STRING", mode="NULLABLE"),
    SchemaField("extra_info", "STRING", mode="NULLABLE"),
    SchemaField("source_ids", "STRING", mode="REPEATED"),
    SchemaField("format", "STRING", mode="REQUIRED"),
]


class BqMetadataRepository(MetadataRepository):
    def __init__(self, project: str, dataset_id: str, table_id: str):
        self._project = project
        self._dataset_id = dataset_id
        self._table_id = table_id
        self._client = Client(project=project)

    def load(self, id: str) -> Metadata:
        pass

    def save(self, metadata: Metadata):
        table_ref = self._create_if_not_exist()
        table = Table(table_ref, METADATA_TABLE_SCHEMA)
        self._client.insert_rows(table, rows=[metadata.asdict])

    def _create_if_not_exist(self):
        dataset_ref = self._client.dataset(self._dataset_id)
        self._client.create_dataset(dataset_ref, exists_ok=True)
        table_ref = dataset_ref.table(self._table_id)
        table = Table(table_ref=table_ref, schema=METADATA_TABLE_SCHEMA)
        self._client.create_table(table, exists_ok=True)
        return table_ref
```

This code shows part of the errors below if I call the `save` method. The part of `*` actually has the project, dataset and table id.
If we call `save` method again, on the second time, the already existing table is properly detected ant insertion succeeds.

```
E           google.api_core.exceptions.NotFound: 404 POST https://bigquery.googleapis.com/bigquery/v2/projects/*****/*****/******/tables/******/insertAll?prettyPrint=false: Table **********:test_dataset.test_table not found.

../../.pyenv/versions/3.11.4/envs/dcraft/lib/python3.11/site-packages/google/cloud/_http/__init__.py:494: NotFound
```

What is the expected way to do this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

An approach could be load data using a `LoadJob` instead `insert_rows`. That way you can use the `write_disposition=WRITE_APPEND` option to create a table if not exists or just append the new data otherwise:

```py
from google.cloud.bigquery import Client, SchemaField, Table, LoadJobConfig

#...

class BqMetadataRepository(MetadataRepository):
    #...

    def save(self, metadata: Metadata):
        job_config = LoadJobConfig(
            schema=METADATA_TABLE_SCHEMA,
            write_disposition="WRITE_APPEND"
        )
        job = self._client.load_table_from_json(
            json_rows=[metadata.asdict],
            destination=f'{self._project}.{self._dataset_id}.{self._table_id}'
            job_config=job_config
        )
        result = job.result()
        print(result)
```

References:

- [BigQuery Job](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/rest/v2/Job)
- [load_table_from_json](https://cloud.google.com/python/docs/reference/bigquery/latest/google.cloud.bigquery.client.Client#google_cloud_bigquery_client_Client_load_table_from_json)